# Override the square bracket operator of string?

Tags: c#, overriding, overloading

I try to change the behaviour of the square bracket operator.
Now my question is if it's even possible to do this.

I know I can create a extension method for String with something like this:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static char Substring(this string value, int position)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

But how can I override the square bracket operator?
This won't work:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static char this[this string value, int position]
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

How can it be done. Or is it even possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You cannot declare indexers in a static class and indexers can't be static.

Comment: There is a proposal named "Extension Everything" - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159. However as of now it's not possible to write extension method for an indexer.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? there is nothing like "square bracket operator" in c#. it's a (reserved) symbol (like parenthesis and curly braces are too). sticking to your example and the other comments: indexing a string is already possible: `var c = "hello world"[0];` yields 'h' of type char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's deal with a couple of concepts one at a time.

[The square bracket operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx) are used for indexing into aggregate objects:

- Arrays
- Indexer properties on objects

Additionally they're used to denote attributes but this is not relevant to this answer.

Now, a string is not an array and thus the string object has a `this[...]` property.

Your question: "how can I override the square bracket operator?" has this answer: Simply put, you override like any other property, **provided** that you can:

1. Inherit from the type that declared it
2. Override it because it is virtual
3. Actually get the effect because you can have code use your new descendant type when constructing objects instead of the original base type

For strings, the criteria are all a no-go for this:

1. You can't inherit from strings, it is a sealed type, and contains mostly external code for performance considerations
2. Since the type is sealed, there is no point in having virtual members
3. You can't substitute the use of the `System.String` type when constructing strings in large swats of the code.

So **override** this for strings? Nope, can't be done.

Then you show an example what you came up with, which is similar to the syntax of an **extension method**.

To recap before continuing:

- To **override** something, we talk about inheritance and polymorphism (virtual member in base class)
- To **extend** something with an **extension method** you can provide on-the-side extra methods to existing types without modifying said types

And yes, you can surely add extension methods to strings, but you can't provide *extension **properties** (yet)*.

The new Roslyn compiler project has a lot of features suggested for it, including an [Extension Everything](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159) feature which could possibly solve this. It is, however, not yet decided upon nor planned nor implemented.

You can create a normal extension method, you just can't redefine, override, or extend, what the `[...]` operators do.

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static char CharAt(this string value, int position)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = "Test";
char c = s.CharAt(2);
```